# Getting “Too many redirects” error with nginx rewrite rule

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

this is nginx.conf.
There is a problem that continues to redirect.
i am getting a "too many redirects" error.
What's problems?

i want "/aaa/test.do" uri to http.
not "/aaa/test.do" uri to https.
please help. Thanks.

```
map $uri $example_org_preferred_proto {
    default https;
    ~^/aaa/test.do http;
}
```

........

```
 server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  www.test.com;

        charset utf-8;

        if ($example_org_preferred_proto = "https") {
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }

        location / {
           proxy_set_header Host                $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server    $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
           proxy_redirect off;
           proxy_buffering off;
           proxy_connect_timeout 60;
           proxy_read_timeout 60;
           proxy_pass   http://wwwtestcom;
        }
}


# HTTPS server
#
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  www.test.com;

    charset utf-8;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      D:/nginx-1.7.10/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  D:/nginx-1.7.10/ssl/key.pem;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  !ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:!EXP:+eNULL:AES256-SHA;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    if ($example_org_preferred_proto = "http") {
        return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
       proxy_set_header Host                $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server    $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_buffering off;
       proxy_connect_timeout 60;
       proxy_read_timeout 60;
       proxy_pass   http://wwwtestcom;
       proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You had quotes missing here ("http" and "https"):

```
map $uri $example_org_preferred_proto {
    default "https";
    ~^/aaa/test.do "http";
}
```

Also, I would suggest to define separate access and error logs for HTTP and HTTPS servers. Checking messages in those log files will help you to debug the issue quickly.